# Approach for plotting 3D animated joints and ability to rotate camera (MATLAB?)

Tags: matlab, csv, video, plot, rotation

I have generated a CSV file from an OpenNI program that tracks skeleton joints.

The CSV file contains the frame number, confidence value, and xyz positions of each joint all separated by columns.

I'd like to plot the extracted points and display them in a video. While I have done this before using MATLAB and generated movie files with it, I was wondering **what would be a good approach to be able to create a video file of these 3D joints *where a user can rotate the video's camera 360 degrees?***

Should I continue to explore that through MATLAB? Is there a way I can do this through OpenNI? Any suggestions would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's the source of the input data? e.g., CT scans, MRI, etc.

Comment: It's skeleton tracking joint data from OpenNI (shoulder points, head, elbow, hands)

Comment: Are you sure OpenNI truly infers depth from a two dimensional image? My apologies if I misunderstand the package. If you have a set of interconnected vertices representing joints mapped in a three dimensional space (with temporal component), you can likely render your animation nicely in OpenGL. See inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GjQelYacgE. The biggest question is how easily you can feed the OpenNI data to OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks - OpenNI's image is 3D (at least there is depth and there are z-coordinate positions for each joint). I extract the joints using a CSV file so I could potentially feed the CSV and extract from it using OpenGL?

Comment: Yes... I would suggest the following: openNI.jointrec(image from camera) --> csv of some format --> ? --> OpenGL display csv data... With this flow, you need to figure out how to export the csv output from openNI in a way that OpenGL understands... Can you find a good resource on interfacing the two libraries?